# SonataUserBundle overriding EditableRolesBuilder

Tags: symfony, overriding, sonata-admin, sonata

Im trying to override EditableRolesBuilder in Security folder.

- I try to make same hierarchy in
  Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Security\EditableRolesBuilder which
  extends the base one Sonata\UserBundle\Security\EditableRolesBuilder
  from vendor but with no success.
- I try to override service in
  Sonata\UserBundle\Resources\config\admin.xml, to pass my custom class
  but i can't find anywhere how to override whole service.This service
  is without parameters but hardcoded class and i cant't pass it in
  config.yml

Comment: Not an easiest one you have to override securityRolesType + transformer to get work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sonata admin if you wish to override security roles handler you have to override 2 services

- sonata.user.editable_role_builder
- sonata.user.form.type.security_roles

And definitions will look like as below

```
    <services>
        <service id="sonata.user.editable_role_builder" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Security\EditableRolesBuilder">
            <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
            <argument type="service" id="sonata.admin.pool" />
            <argument>%security.role_hierarchy.roles%</argument>
        </service>
        <service id="sonata.user.form.type.security_roles" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\SecurityRolesType">
            <tag name="form.type" alias="sonata_security_roles" />
            <argument type="service" id="sonata.user.editable_role_builder" />
        </service>
    </services>
```

For reference see [**`Sonata Admin Override Security Roles Handler`**](https://github.com/dianuj89/Soanta-Editable-Roles-Builder)